# ASP.NET & Entity Framework 4.0 data not refreshing on screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, caching

I've written a 2-tier C# asp.net application.

Everything works OK, but if I modify the SQL Server data using the management console, the changes are not displayed on screen. It seems the application reads the data from a cached instance.

I have tried everything to make sure it's not a browser cache issue... the data remains static until I restart the app or restar the web site. even clearing IIS cache doesn't help. If the data is updated by the application, it works ok... Any info about a default setting on the EF that caches data automatically?

I'm running Win Server 2k8 and SQL Server 2008, but the problem was there also for SQL2005.

Comment: Duplicate question. Check this thread for answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617987/ef-4-0-model-caching-the-data-and-does-not-detect-the-modified-data

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this, but maybe the SqlCacheDependency can help you.
See this article for more info: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/04/29/2929.aspx